# In $\Delta ABC$, $AB=\sqrt 5$, $BC=1$, $AC=2$. $I$ is the incenter of $\Delta ABC$ and the circumcircle of $\Delta IBC$ cuts $AB$ at $P$. Find $BP$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Question: In $\Delta ABC$, $AB=\sqrt 5$, $BC=1$, and $AC=2$. $I$ is the incenter of $\Delta ABC$ and the circumcircle of $\Delta IBC$ cuts $AB$ at $P$. Compute the length of $\overline{BP}$.

[image]

Using coordinates, I believe the answer is $BP=\sqrt{5}-2$. However, I am unsure how to arrive at this without using coordinate geometry.

The final answer seems to imply that $AP=AC$, so I think that this is the key to solving the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be the intersection between the incircle and sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively.

Since $I$ is the incenter, $BI$ is the angle bisector and so $C\hat{B}I = I\hat{B}P$. Since $C\hat{B}I$ and $C\hat{P}I$ are determined by the same arc of the circumference, they are congruent, and for the same reason, $I\hat{B}P = I\hat{C}P$. But then $C\hat{P}I = C\hat{B}I = I\hat{B}P = I\hat{C}P$, which means $\triangle CIP$ is isosceles and $PI = CI$. But then triangles $\triangle GPI$ and $\triangle CHI$ are both right triangles with hypotenuses equal and length and a third side also equal in length (since $GI$ and $IH$ are both the radius of the incircle), which means they are congruent and so $I\hat{P}G = I\hat{C}H$. Thus, it follows that $I\hat{P}G + C\hat{P}I = I\hat{C}H + I\hat{C}P$, so triangle $ACP$ is isosceles and $AP = AC$. Thus $BP = \sqrt{5} - 2$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We want to show $$\angle BCA=\angle CPA$$
In $\triangle BIC$, we have
\begin{align*}
\angle BIC&=180^{\circ}-\frac{\angle B}{2}-\frac{\angle C}{2}\\
&=180^{\circ}-45^{\circ}-\frac{\angle B}{2}
\end{align*}
As B, P, I, C are concyclic, we have
$$\angle BPC=\angle BIC=180^{\circ}-45^{\circ}-\frac{\angle B}{2}$$
$$\angle CPA=180^{\circ}-\angle BPC=45+\frac{\angle B}{2}$$
By using the angle sum of triangle, we have
$$\angle BCP=180^{\circ}-\angle B-\angle BIC=45^{\circ}-\frac{\angle B}{2}$$
$$\angle BCA=90^\circ-\angle BCP=45^\circ+\frac{\angle B}{2}=\angle CPA$$
This shows that $\triangle CAP$ is an isostriangle so AP=AC and BP$=\sqrt5-2$